# Unmarshaling XML CDATA strings as literals using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

Consider the following simple `XML` string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
    <value name="test">abcd</value>
</example>
```

The following code defines 2 `Java` classes (`Example.class` and `Value.class`) that can be used to produce the above `XML` output, for the string value `abcd`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "example")
public class Example {
  private Value value;
  private Example() {}
  public Value getValue() { return value; }

  public void setValue(Value value) { this.value = value; }

  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  private static final class Value {
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    private String name;
    public Value() {}
    public String getValue() { return value; }


     public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
      }
  }
```

To unmarshall (deserialize) the above `XML` string into the original `Example` object it was produced from, one can use the following code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Example.class);
    String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
      "<example>\n" +
      "    <value name=\"test\">abcd</value>\n" +
      "</example>";
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Example v = (Example)um.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes()));
    System.out.println(v.getValue().getValue());
  }
```

However, if the string value in the above `main()` method is changed from `abcd` to `abcd<>` or any other `CDATA` string, the unmarshaller throws an exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

A [proposed solution](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html) is to use a custom `DOMHandler` with an `XmlAnyElement` annotation, but it does not seem to work.

Is there any way of deserializing the `abcd<>` string as a literal (i.e., without enclosing it in a `CDATA` section)?

Comment: The proposed solution you link to (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html) is to keep part of the unmarshalled XML as a `String`.  It still requires the XML be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way of deserializing the abcd<> string as a literal
>   (i.e., without enclosing it in a CDATA section)?

No, because your XML won't be valid.

> The problem is to try to unmarshal an unknown input, therefore such
>   preprocessing is not possible

You will need to ensure your inputs are valid XML to use any XML tool.

**Invalid XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
    <value name="test">abcd<></value>
</example>
```

When you tried to parse the above XML you got the following exception.  The exception comes from the underlying parser used by JAXB.  XML parsers rely on angle brackets representing element tags.  Special care must be taken when including them in element content.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

**Made Valid Using Parsed Character Data**

One way to make the XML valid is to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.  Your JAXB implementation will unmarshal the XML value `abcd&lt;&gt;` to the `String` value `abcd<>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
    <value name="test">abcd&lt;&gt;</value>
</example>
```

**Made Valid Using Character Data**

Another way to make the XML valid is to wrap the character content in a CDATA block.  JAXB will unmarshal `<![CDATA[abcd<>]]>` as `abcd<>`.  On marshaling it will put the content to XML as `abcd&lt;&gt;`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
    <value name="test"><![CDATA[abcd<>]]></value>
</example>
```

Comment: You are right in all accounts, CDATA does seem to be the only way around.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to replace special characters `"&'<>` with character references `&qout;&amp;` etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to replace the special character in your xml string to below.

```
abcd&lt;&gt; instead of `abcd<>`
```

Comment: The idea is to avoid doing that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a method that appends CDATA tags before unmarshalling?

```
 public String addCdataTags (String yourString){
        return "<![CDATA[" + yourString + "]]>"
     }
```

This should take care of those CDATA Strings mistakenly seen as xml element tags

Comment: Where should that method be added?

Comment: right before invoking unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());

Comment: This is just a demo. The problem is to try to unmarshal an unknown input, therefore such preprocessing is not possible.